# JFace: how to add multiple selection to a cell in a TableViewer

Tags: java, swt, jface, multi-select, tableviewer

This question is about how I could add a multi-selection `ComboBoxCellEditor`, or a multiple `BooleanCellEditor` to a cell in a `TableViewer`. The main aim is to have a multi selection in a cell.

I am using the snippets at http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFaceSnippets and http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/, and I now have a fairly good Table using `TableView` with all editing supports, label providers, content providers. Inside the cells I now have a `TextCellEditor` or a `ComboBoxCellEditor`.

The thing is: I want a multiple selection, and I don't know how.

1. The code of `org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.edit.editor.ComboBoxCellEditor` seems to have multipleselection, but I am having always a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` while trying to use the external Nebula classes
2. The JFace snippet `Snippet061FakedNativeCellEditor` provides me with only one checkbox, and adapting this code to my code is difficult.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're not adding those nebula JARs/Projects to your buildpath/runtime.
2. You'll have to extend your own `CellEditor`. Inside it, you can create basically anything you want, as long as it's a `Control`. I'm pretty sure you can sneak more than one widget in the `createControl` protected method of `CellEditor`.

Comment: Hi GGrec: (1): It surely is a missing class path in runtime, I have to use an inclusion of bundle inside my manifest file, since .classpath is not enough (i'm developing an Eclipse plugin)

Comment: Hi GGrec: (2) Your hint about `createControl` is excellent, but if I want to have an array of Button (for multiple selection effect), how can I return this Button[] as a Control ?

Comment: @JA Keep in mind that a `Composite` is a `Control` too. So basically you may set any composite as control. :-)